# Google maps not displaying in full size as the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

You can have a look here, please click on `BEKIJK TO SEE THE MAP` http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/ligging/

JS:

```
 var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

$('.show-map').click(function(){
    $('.ligging-ar').toggle();
    $('.to-hide').fadeToggle("fast",function(){
        $('#map_canvas').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

//LE

```
$('.show-map').click(function(){
    $('.ligging-ar').toggle();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    $('.to-hide').fadeToggle("fast",function(){
        $('#map_canvas').fadeToggle();
    });
```

Comment: Broken link on 12/08/2015

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the JavaScript changing the visibility of the element.

This should work:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: I tried this already but doesn't work look in my posts how I updated my code

Comment: the trigger has to be called after the visibility has changed

Answer (score 1):

Google maps often has problems if the element that will hold the map is hidden when the page is rendered, or indeed if the element is resized.

You should be able to resolve this by calling `resizeMap();` after making the map visible.

If you are using V3 of the google maps API then use the following

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

Comment: I tried this already but doesn't work look in my posts how I updated my code

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with the new API. If I see it right you should call the resizeMap() function after toggling your mapcanvas.
Please try this:

```
$('.show-map').click(function(){
    $('.ligging-ar').toggle();    
    $('.to-hide').fadeToggle("fast",function(){
        $('#map_canvas').fadeToggle();
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked is this, to place the resize method on callback..in the fadeOut:

```
$('.show-map').click(function(){
    $('.ligging-ar').toggle();
    $('.to-hide').fadeToggle("fast",function(){
        $('#map_canvas').fadeToggle();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
```